# JS Compiler / Package Manager for use with version control

Tags: javascript, version-control, build-automation, package-managers, gruntjs

I'm trying to grasp a bit of an idea here.  And hoping someone can help clarify the best practice.

How do teams or pairs approach using a build system for javascript like grunt.js ?

I really want to break our large javascript files into smaller pieces and converting to AMD/Require isn't an option right now.

It seems the easiest way is to concatenate and minify to a master file.  And we are using version control (SVN).

So I'm wondering what the best practice is here?

Are we asking for constant conflicts with the production file?  How do other teams approach this?

Hope i made my question clear enough.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently faced a similar dilemma at my organization. Using AMD or RequireJS wasn't an option due the the sheer amount of legacy JavaScript code we have.

We [ultimately went with grunt](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2012/06/19/why-we-use-node-dot-js-and-grunt-to-build-javascript/) and came up with a "build" task that concatenates and minifies. Then, there's a completely separate "deploy" task that gzip's the files and uploads to Amazon S3.

We don't check in our concatenated/minified code to source control. In general, it's a good operational practice to have separate build and deploy tasks for your source code. For larger development teams, the deploy/build process would traditionally be done in a CI tool that runs whenever someone commits to SVN/git.

In your case, a simpler arrangement would be if you just manually deployed code from your development machine instead of have it automated from a CI tool. The problem with this setup is it's easy to run into conflicts with other team members.

That said, there is a growing number of open-source ([Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) or cloud-hosted ([CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)) tools that might be worthwhile for you to look into.

Comment: Thanks for the response smithclay.  We had been running into similar obvious issues, and decided to begin conversion to an async loader instead.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is a valid solution.  However, like smithclay mentioned, its a bit too easy to run into conflicts for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not commit the output. Use a ci tool like teamcity to build and deploy. Only commit source files to source control.

Comment: I get ignoring the compiled file.  But Team City seems a bit overkill for just javascript concatenation and compression build.  Is this really how teams do it?  Thanks again.